# "Done, but with errors on page", line 575?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am working on a JavaScript application that works in Firefox and Chrome, but breaks in Internet Explorer 7.
[image]

When I click on the above message, the first error shown refers me to "line 575". My JavaScript file happens to have only 566 lines (i.e., there is no line 575 in the JavaScript file and The HTML page is much shorter).

*Line: 575

Char: 68*

My question is: what line is "line 575" referring to in the above example?

Comment: Turn on script debugging in IE and try again.  Which version of IE are you on?

Comment: Recommend using a browser with a proper error console like Chrome, Firefox+Firebug, Opera's Dragonfly, or a more recent version of IE (8 and 9 both have "F12 developer tools"). Open the console, if the tool requires it (some do) click the button to enable script debugging, refresh the page, and you should get more useful information.

Comment: verify you don't have `console.log()` in your js

Comment: Marek, IE7. I edited the question. (I keep an old version of IE for testing.) I also turned on 'script debugging', I will now Google "'script debugging' and 'internet explorer'".

Comment: You can try and use [Microsoft Script Debugger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Script_Debugger) . it helped me a lot in IE6/7 testing. though once its installs, the IE crashes on a lot of bugs (and opens the debugger to show you where the error is). use it only if your IE is used for testing.